# Why is there a difference in behavior between these two pattern matches in a for comprehension?

Tags: scala

Consider this `Map[String, Any]`:

```
val m1 = Map(("k1" -> "v1"), ("k2" -> 10))
```

Now let's write a `for`:

```
scala> for ((a, b) <- m1) println(a + b)
k1v1
k210
```

So far so good.

Now let's specify the type of the second member:

```
scala> for ((a, b: String) <- m1) println(a + b)
k1v1

scala> for ((a, b: Integer) <- m1) println(a + b)
k210
```

Here, as I specify a type, filtering takes place, which is great.

Now say I want to use an Array[Any] instead:

```
val l1 = Array("a", 2)
```

Here, things break:

```
scala> for (v: String <- l1) println(v)
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String) => Unit
 required: (Any) => ?
```

My double question is:

- why doesn't the second match filter as well?
- is there a way to express such filtering in the second scenario without using a dirty `isInstanceOf`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, the latter example doesn't work because it isn't spec'ed to. There's some discussion as to what would be the reasonable behavior. Personally, I'd expect it to work just like you. The thing is that:

```
val v: String = (10: Any) // is a compile error
(10: Any) match {
    case v: String =>
} // throws an exception
```

If you are not convinced by this, join the [club](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/900). :-) Here's a workaround:

```
for (va @ (v: String) <- l1) println(v)
```

Note that in Scala 3, you can:

```
for (case v: String <- l1) println(v)
```

Comment: I definitely would like to join this club as it is confusing right now! Is there a Scala ticket for this? Workaround works great, thanks.

Comment: @ebruchez Actually, yes. An old one, and opened by none other than D.R. MacIver. I'll link it in the answer.

Answer (score 9):

The main reason for the speced behavior is that we want to encourage people to add type annotations, for clarity. If in for comprehensions, they get potentially very costly filter operations instead, that's a trap we want to avoid. However, I agree that we should make it easier to specify that something is a pattern. Probably a single pair of parens should suffice.

```
val x: String = y       // type check, can fail at compile time
val (x: String) = y     // pattern match, can fail at run time

for (x: String <- ys)   // type check, can fail at compile time
for ((x: String) <- ys) // pattern match, can filter at run time
```

Comment: That syntax would make sense. Something for Scala 2.9?

Comment: That syntax is pretty subtle.  Why not use `case` to distinguish the pattern matching forms?

Comment: I hadn't seen the rationalization before. +1! Everyone knows that adding parens adds a runtime penalty. It's Lisp.