# Why scala's pattern maching does not work in for loops for type matching?

Tags: scala, casting, pattern-matching

I'm coding against an API that gives me access to remote file system. The API returns a list of files and directories as list of node objects (parent to file and directory).

I want to work only on a directories, ignoring files. I've tried to use type pattern matching in `for` loop but it does not work:

```
for {
    dir: CSDir <- workarea.getChildren() // <-- I'm getting an error here complaining about type conversion
} {
    println(dir)
}
```

Here is a similar example using scala basic objects to run it without dependencies:

```
val listOfBaseObjects:List[Any] = List[Any]("a string", 1:Integer);

for (x: String <- listOfObjects) {
  println(x)
}
```

I end up using a regular pattern matching in side of for loop and that works fine:

```
// This works fien
for (child <- workarea.getChildren()) {
  child match {
    case dir: CSDir => println(dir)
    case _ => println("do not nothing")
  }
}
```

### Question:

Can you tell me why the first /second example does not work in scala 1.9?

In the "Programming in Scala" the  `for` loop is advertised  to use the  same  pattern matching as the `match` so it should work.

If the for and match are different it would be great if you could point me to some articles with more details. What about pattern matching in assignment?

### Update:

I can't accept an answer that states that it is impossible to skip elements in for loop as this contradicts with the "Prog. in scala". Here is a fragment from section 23.1:

> `pat <- expr` ... The pattern `pat` gets matched one-by-one against all elements of that list. ... if the match fails, no MatchError is thrown. Instead, the element is simply discarded from the iteration

and indeed the following example works just fine:

```
scala> val list = List( (1,2), 1, 3, (3,4))
scala> for ((x,y) <- list) { println (x +","+ y) }
1,2
3,4
```

Why then type matching does not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952124/why-is-there-a-difference-in-behavior-between-these-two-pattern-matches-in-a-for

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the [long-standing issue 900](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-900) and has been discussed many times before. The common workaround is to use something like:

```
for (y@(_y:String) <- listOfBaseObjects) {
    println(y)
}
```

A nicer version is provided by Jason Zaugg in the comments to the above-mentioned ticket:

```
object Typed { def unapply[A](a: A) = Some(a) }

for (Typed(y : String) <- listOfBaseObjects) {
    println(y)
}
```

Comment: can someone explain to me what kind of syntactic sugar is  y@(_y:String) I only know that this is some kind of variable binding used for pattern matching. Sorry newbie here.. EDIT: found my answer in : http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-binders

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is essentially: iterate over all elements of `workarea.getChildren()` that are of type `CSDir` (in other words: matching some criteria). <del>Ordinary loop/for comprehension iterates over *all* elements. You cannot say: iterate over all elements having this type and skip others. You must be more explicit.</del>

What do you think about:

```
workarea.getChildren() collect {case dir: CSDir => dir} foreach println
```

It does exactly what you want: *collect* all elements of `workarea.getChildren()` and *for each* of them call `println`.

Comment: According to the "Prog. in scala": `pat <- expr` ... "The pattern `pat` gets matched one-by-one against all elemetns of that list. ... if the match fails, no MatchError is thrown. Instead, the element is simply discarded from the iteration" -- So it should work discarding not matching elements

Comment: See update to the question that shows that you can use for loop to skip over the elements. I guess that it is translated to collect with  foreach

Comment: @PiotrCzapla: good catch, here is another example of this behavior: `for(Some(x) <- Seq(Some(7), None, Some(42))) {println(x)}`. I wasn't aware of this mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
val listOfBaseObjects: List[Any] = List[Any]("a string", 1:Integer);

for (x <- listOfBaseObjects if x.isInstanceOf[String]) {
  println(x)
}
```

Comment: Compared to other solutions, this has a drawback - the `x` will be still `Any` inside of the `for` body, not `String`.