# Is it possible to pattern match on type in a Scala for expression?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, for-comprehension

I'm trying to use a for expression to map over an Option, but I only want to match if the contents of the Option are of a specific type. What I thought would work is this:

```scala
for {
  vcs: Mercurial <- maybeVcs
} yield vcs
```

But that yields the following compile error:

```
<console>:76: error: type mismatch;
 found   : sbtrelease.Mercurial => sbtrelease.Mercurial
 required: sbtrelease.Vcs => ?
                vcs: Mercurial <- get (releaseVcs in Compile)
                               ^
```

Is it possible to pattern match on type in a for expression?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why scala's pattern maching does not work in for loops for type matching?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394034/why-scalas-pattern-maching-does-not-work-in-for-loops-for-type-matching)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does pattern matching in Scala not work with variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078022/why-does-pattern-matching-in-scala-not-work-with-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really straightforward if you use `collect` instead of `for`:

```
trait A
case class B(x: Int) extends A
case class C(y: Int) extends A

val someB: Option[A] = Some(B(2))
val someC: Option[A] = Some(C(2))
val noneA: Option[A] = None
someB.collect { case n: B => n }   // Some(B(2))
someC.collect { case n: B => n }   // None
noneA.collect { case n: B => n }   // None
```

Comment: That's what I wound up doing, but the for comprehension feels cleaner to me (at least if it worked:), since a pattern match for a single case seems awkward.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that this pattern match does not work is actually a bug (at least its not in accordance with the spec). See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-900.

However, there is a simple workaround.
Define somewhere the following object:

```
object Id { def unapply[T](x:T) = Some(x) }
```

Now you can use `Id(x)` as a pattern match that matches everything, and just binds `x` to whatever it matched. So basically a pointless construct, since `Id(pattern)` is the same as `pattern`.

However, it has one effect: A type annotation inside `Id(...)` will not be interpreted as a type annotation, but as a type pattern. Thus

```
for {
  Id(vcs: Mercurial) <- maybeVcs
} yield vcs
```

will have the effect you desire. (And differently from [Bob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33577145/2646248), the overall expression will have type `Seq[Mercurial]` and not `Seq[Vcs]`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ugly test:

```
for {
  vcs <- maybeVcs
  if vcs.instanceof[Mercurial]
} yield vcs
```