# explanation on scala for comprehension with Option

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I have the following definition:

```
def f: Option[String] = Some(null)
```

the following evaluates to None:

```
for {x:String <- f} yield {
  x
}
```

the following evaluates to Some(null):

```
for {x <- f} yield {
  x
}
```

the following evaluates to Some(null):

```
f.map((x:String) => x)
```

I'm wondering why is there differences between them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The desugaring happens in the parser, so `-Xprint:parser` shows the difference:

```
$ scala -Xprint:parser
Welcome to Scala 2.12.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> for (s: String <- (Some(null): Option[String])) yield s
[[syntax trees at end of                    parser]] // <console>
package $line3 {
  object $read extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    object $iw extends scala.AnyRef {
      def <init>() = {
        super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      object $iw extends scala.AnyRef {
        def <init>() = {
          super.<init>();
          ()
        };
        val res0 = (Some(null): Option[String]).withFilter(((check$ifrefutable$1) => check$ifrefutable$1: @scala.unchecked match {
  case (s @ (_: String)) => true
  case _ => false
})).map(((s: String) => s))
      }
    }
  }
}

res0: Option[String] = None
```

This surprises me because I thought filtering in this way was a feature people wanted but wasn't implemented.

The type pattern is just an instanceof test, so null fails that test.

Without the filter:

```
scala> for (s <- (Some(null): Option[String])) yield s
[[syntax trees at end of                    parser]] // <console>
package $line4 {
  object $read extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    object $iw extends scala.AnyRef {
      def <init>() = {
        super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      object $iw extends scala.AnyRef {
        def <init>() = {
          super.<init>();
          ()
        };
        val res1 = (Some(null): Option[String]).map(((s) => s))
      }
    }
  }
}

res1: Option[String] = Some(null)
```

In 2.9:

```
$ scala29
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.3 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_38).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> for (s: String <- (Some(null): Option[String])) yield s
res0: Option[String] = Some(null)
```

so the filtering feature was added in 2.10.x.

Edit: so actually, [this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-900) is what you don't get:

```
scala> for (s: String <- (Some("x"): Option[Any])) yield s
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String => String
 required: Any => ?
       for (s: String <- (Some("x"): Option[Any])) yield s
                      ^
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952124/why-is-there-a-difference-in-behavior-between-these-two-pattern-matches-in-a-for

Answer (score 1):

Well... the first thing that I will say is that "When in Scala-land, stay as far as possible from a null-monster". They are dangerous.

Now...as to understand this behaviour, the first thing that you need to try in Scala-shell is following,

```
scala> val n = null
n: Null = null
```

So... In Scala `null` is an instance of this class `Null`.

Now... lets see what happens when we mix this `null` with `Option`,

```
scala> val nullOpt1 = Option(null)
nullOpt1: Option[Null] = None

scala> val nullOpt2 = Some(null)
nullOpt2: Some[Null] = Some(null)
```

Notice the difference... between the two... So basically Scala people thought that there may be people who want to wrap a `null` into an `Option`... so they allowed them to `explicitly` use `Some.apply` to wrap that `null` into an `Option`. Where as the use of `Option.apply` behave more "intelligently" and gives you a `None` when you try to wrap a `null`.

Now... lets first look at how `map` is implemented for an `Option`,

```
final def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] =
  if (isEmpty) None else Some(f(this.get))
```

And now... it should be clear as to "why `Some(null).map((x: String) => x)` gives you `Some(null)` ?".

As for to understand the `for` cases... that will require a little understanding of how `for` is implemented for `Option` with the use of `Repr`'s. And the behaviour will become clear.

Comment: @som-snytt yes that is exactly the point. So... whatever "value" (even if null) was in that `Some` will be returned by `this.get` and the `f` in this case is just `x => x`, hence this results in `Some(null)`

Comment: I can understand why Some(null).map((x: String) => x) gives me Some(null), what I don't understand is why for {x:String <- f} yield x gives me None, because, theoretically they should be the same.