# Typed pattern in For expressions

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

According to *Programming in Scala*, Section 23.4, a for expression can contain patterns, where a generic form looks like this:

```
for (pat <- expr1) yield expr2
```

which would be translated to the following by the compiler:

```
expr1 withFilter {
  case pat => true
  case _ => false
} map {
  case pat => expr2
}
```

My question is whether this would work with *typed patterns*, if that is the case clearly the following in ambiguous:

```
val t = List("a", 1, 1.0)
for ((y : String) <- t) yield y
```

Here the `y: String` gets interpreted as a type declaration, not a typed pattern (and does not compile). However, the extended form works OK:

```
t withFilter {
  case y :String => true
  case _ => false
} map {
  case y : String => y
}
```

Just wondering if there is a way to express typed patterns in that position in a for expression.

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394034/why-scalas-pattern-maching-does-not-work-in-for-loops-for-type-matching, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952124/why-is-there-a-difference-in-behavior-between-these-two-pattern-matches-in-a-for and https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/900

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@` to **bind the matched pattern** for the variable. like:

```
for (s @ (_x : String) <- t) yield s
```

In there `(_x : String)` is a type pattern of `s`, and `s` is the variable.

and the above code will be translated to:

```
t withFilter {
  case s @ (_x: String) => true
  case _ => false
} map {
  case y: String => y
}
```